# Adobe Captivate 5.5 download

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, migration

I have a license key for Adobe Captivate 5.5 from my XP machine and I am trying to download it on my Windows 7 computer.  Every link I can find has taken me to Adobe Captivate 7...any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried contacting adobe?

Comment: I am looking for contact info now...hopefully they will have a solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. [Deactivate the license](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/activation-deactivation-products.html#how-to) on your Windows XP machine, in case you haven't already.
2. [Sign in](https://www.adobe.com/account/sign-in.adobedotcom.html?returnURL=https://www.adobe.com/account.html) with your Adobe account or create a new one. As an alternative, visit the [Download a free trial of Acrobat XI Pro](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=acrobat_pro) page.

   This step is required to set the session cookies on your browser which grant you access to the trial(s).
3. Download the official Captivate 5.5 trial directly from Adobe:

   - **English / French / German / Japanese**
     http://trials2.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/CPTV/5_5/win32/Captivate_5_5_WWEFDJ.7z
   - **Spanish / Italian**
     http://trials2.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/CPTV/5_5/win32/Captivate_5_5_WWSI.7z
   - **Korean**
     http://trials2.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/CPTV/5_5/win32/Captivate_5_5_KO.7z
4. Extract the content of the `.7z` archive using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
5. Install the program using your serial number. When everything is up and running, make a backup of the setup package.

### References

- [Adobe Direct Download Links Without Akamai Download Manager](http://technolux.blogspot.jp/2011/02/adobe-direct-download-links-less-akamai.html)